# print(i, end=' ') SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
list = ['asdasd', 'caqwe', 'prtdf']

for i in list:
    print(i, end=' ')
```

Esto imprimiría:

> asdasd caqwe prtdf

Pero cuando ejecuto la función, me muestra el siguiente error:

> ```
> File "Prueba A.py", line 4
>     print(i, end=' ')
>                 ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Comment: Pregunta fundamental: ¿Python 2 o Python 3?

Comment: Esto funciona "correctamente" en **Python 3.x**. Lo de correctamente, entre comillas, es porque estás sobreescribiendo un constructor de python, [list()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists), con una variable. Llámale a la lista de otra manera.

Comment: Lo que describe el usuario sólo se reproduce en un intérprete de Python 2. Si queremos que esta pregunta sea útil para otras personas en su situación, debería estar correctamente etiquetada. A mí no se me permite hace la edición. ¿Puede alguien con más privilegios añadir la etiqueta correcta?

Comment: Si el usuario no se hace cargo, porque deberiamos nosotros suponer el escenario? no, no podemos arreglar algo que tiene que decidir el usuario... @JorgeLuis

Comment: Porque stack overflow es un juego a tres bandas: perguntadores, respondedores y lectores. De los tres grupos el más numeroso es el tercero y es para quien se hace todo esto. Obviamente a Savir no le importa esta pregunta, pero puede haber gente en el futuro a la que le resulte útil. Pero sólo le será útil si está correctamente etiquetada. @gbianchi

Comment: @JorgeLuis pregunta sin votos, respuestas no aceptadas.. si pensas que vale la pena, crea una nueva pregunta como corresponde y luego respondela. Esta, asi como esta, no le va servir a nadie, y no, no podemos suponer el escenario de OP...

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Argumento end al llamar a print en Python 2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/594149)

Answer (score 0):

Como el error que describes no se reproduce en Python3 y sí en Python2, asumo que estás intentando ejecutar el código con un intérprete de Python2.

En Python2 `print` no es una función, sino una sentencia.
Por lo tanto no puede recibir argumentos keyword.
Escribir `print(i, end=" ")` produce el mismo error que si escribieras la tupla: `(i, end=" ")`.
No tiene sentido escribir ese segundo elemento dentro de una tupla.

Lo que se suele hacer en Python2 es:

```
for i in lista:
    print i,
```

La coma al final tras `i` hace que añada un espacio, no un salto de línea.

Si quieres usar en el intérprete de Python2 la función `print` como se usa en Python3 debes usar el módulo `future`.
Esta importación deshabilitará la sentencia `print` de Python2.

```
from __future__ import print_function
```