# Argumento end al llamar a print en Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.x

Cuando uso este código en el intérprete de Python 2:

```py
for palabra in ("Hola", "mundo"):
    print(palabra, end=" ")
```

obtengo el siguiente error:

> ```
> File "codeA.py", line 2
>     print(palabra, end=' ')
>                       ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Esperaría que imprimiera ambas palabras separadas por un espacio.
Sé que en Python 2 `print` no es una función como en Python 3.
¿Cómo puedo conseguir el mismo resultado en Python 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Python2 [`print`](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/v2.7.2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print) no es una [función](https://peps.python.org/pep-3105/), sino una sentencia.
Por lo tanto no puede recibir argumentos keyword.
Escribir `print(palabra, end=" ")` produce el mismo error que si escribieras la tupla: `(palabra, end=" ")`.
No tiene sentido escribir ese segundo elemento dentro de una tupla.

Lo que se suele hacer en Python2 es:

```
for palabra in lista:
    print palabra,
```

La coma al final tras `palabra` hace que añada un espacio, no un salto de línea.
En caso de que quieras otro separador tendrás que componer tú mismo la cadena.
Por ejemplo: `", ".join(["Hola", "mundo"])` para imprimir `Hola, mundo`.

Si quieres usar en el intérprete de Python2 la función `print` como se usa en Python3 debes usar el módulo [`future`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/__future__.html).
Está disponible a partir de Python 2.6.
Esta importación deshabilitará la sentencia `print` de Python2.

```
from __future__ import print_function
```